# OpenLayers 3 - full screen button - icon not visible on mobile Firefox

Tags: firefox, mobile, fullscreen, openlayers-3

On mobile devices, OpenLayers 3 - full screen icon, in case of Mozilla Firefox doesn't show.

Is there a way to solve this or set an icon myself to show on every device?

Thanks,

Eylul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $('.ol-full-screen-false').attr('title', 'Visualizza a schermo intero');
  $('.ol-full-screen-false').html('<img src="icons/fullscreen_s.png"/>');

  if (document.addEventListener)
  {
    document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', fullscreenHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', fullscreenHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', fullscreenHandler, false);
  }

  function fullscreenHandler()
  {
    if (document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement !== null)
    {
      $('.ol-full-screen-true').attr('title', 'Chiudi la visualizzione a schermo intero');
      $('.ol-full-screen-true').html('<img src="icons/close_s.png"/>');

      $('.ol-full-screen-false').attr('title', 'Visualizza a schermo intero');
      $('.ol-full-screen-false').html('<img src="icons/fullscreen_s.png"/>');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily set your own icon using the `label` and `labelActive` constructor options of `ol.control.FullScreen`.

Comment: I could not set image in this way, and I needed different tips for entering and exiting fullscreen. I wrote my solution as another answer for anyone might need it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Fontawesome expand icon:

```
var fspan = document.createElement('i');
fspan.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-expand');
...
// use it in map control definition
new ol.control.FullScreen({ label: fspan, tipLabel: 'Fullscreen' })
```